# Two different JSON views with Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization

Consider the following, I have a `Job` class that has inputs and one output. I have the following in my job.rb

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(include: [:inputs,:output])
  end
```

So this has been working very well and my `JobController` has been dolling out well formatted and useful JSON responses.

I am working on a way to display a version of the Job JSON to the user that only showed the inputs, so I did the following and got some weird behavior:

`@job.to_json(include: [:inputs])`

This method ignores the options passed to it, and calls the **as_json** method on the model

So my question is, once you have defined **as_json**, how do you get a different json *view* of the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to pass output and inputs by default :

```
def as_json( options = { :include => {:inputs, :output} } )
   super(options)
end
```

then you can pass your options for special cases :

```
@job.as_json( :include => {:inputs} )
```

More info here : http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/